# rate of change of spring potential energy $\frac{dU}{dt}$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, hamiltonian-formalism, spring

Suppose we have a setup like this. In orange are two wooden sticks sort of things, and they are attached to the block of mass $m$(as usual) at a joint which is hinge type something. A similar connection is with spring and with the ground.The block is moving off to the right with velocity $v$. The spring is already extended by a length $l$. I want to find the rate of change of spring potential energy at the instant.

If the block moves towards right then I think the spring is going to move a little bit to the right, not staying perfectly vertical and in that case there would be some sort of angle $\phi$ between force and displacement. But that case is difficult to imagine.
Any other ideas/hints?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I've decided to solve this thing the Hamiltonian way.(as suggested by Bernhard). Even though I don't know much of it, this is my attempt.[image]

I've read here [basic intro](http://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath523/kmath523.htm)(I didn't understand much of Wikipedia, as it was too technical). So now I know I have to make a variable $H=T+V$(the hamiltonian) and do something. Now the question is about $\frac{dU}{dt}$ at any time $t$ where at $t=0$, $\gamma=45^o$ (for ease of coordinates).

$$H=T+V=\frac{1}{2}m\dot x^2+\frac{k}{2}(\sqrt{(Rsin\gamma-\frac{R}{\sqrt{2}}-l-l_0)^2+(Rcos\gamma - \frac{R}{\sqrt{2}})^2}-l_0)^2$$

I've assumed sticks, spring as massless. $l_0$ is the natural length of spring.

What should I do ahead? Please try this problem in simplest language, as I don't know if this involves something difficult like tensors etc. I don't know if this is the place to ask something like this, or if this problem can be solved in Hamiltonian at all. Thanks a lot.

Comment: For these kind of problems, I think it is good to first think about the number of degrees of freedom, before continuing. Is the left block fixed? Then I think you have. You can either take two angles, or two position coordinates of the joint. Maybe you want to have a look at: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_mechanics http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_mechanics

Comment: @Bernhard: I've just passed high school, so I don't think I know those things. If you could elaborate in a simple language using any mechanics, I'll be able to use that in future problems. Thanks.

Comment: @AshishGaurav Just ignore the movement of spring towards right, as you have get this problem solved on this instant itself.[When spring is vertical , for a small time $dt$]

Comment: @Bernhard: OK; I've read [this](http://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath523/kmath523.htm). I'm thinking of a solution in the Hamiltonian terms. I thought it this way: the left wooden stick is fixed at one end to the ground, so let that angle be $\gamma$, and the position of block be $x$. Let the origin for this question(in xy plane) be at the fixing point of the left stick. How do I proceed?

Answer (score 1):

You are very right in your approach.
Just ignore the movement of the spring towards right as we have to work at this very instant, where spring is vertical.
$$ {F}=\mathbb Ky =\dfrac{dU}{dy}$$
$$\dfrac{dU}{dt}=\dfrac{dU}{dy}\times \dfrac{dy}{dt};$$
$$\dfrac{dx}{dt}=v$$
Constraint in motion:$$dy=dx \times tan\theta$$
And so the answer.
$$=>\dfrac{dU}{dt}=\mathbb Klv \ tan\theta;$$

There is no problem in your answer.

Comment: thanks for the confirmation, but now that the discussion has turned to Hamiltonian mechanics, I'll wait for an answer in that way.

Comment: @AshishGaurav Well it's very correct and even i would be pleased to see a answer in other variant. :p . You are an Indian , right ? I'm too an Indian , but we are not taught Lagrangian and Hamiltonian Mechanics till high school....... Have you studied them for yourself?

Comment: Yes, that's true, and I have given the link above in comments. You might want to go over and have a look.

Comment: @AshishGaurav Still Newton's Laws are best. Without much of mathematics involved. Pure physics at its  best.....

Comment: Yes but some things become difficult that way. "This" is also pure physics, maybe better.

Comment: Can you guys please suggest a site which explains this Hamilton mechanics in simpler terms? (I am Indian too...class 10). Getting ready for JEE, that's why

Comment: @SaurabhRaje I still go with Newton's Law and JEE never asks questions which can't be solved by these.I am appearing for JEE2013 in a week and have never read Hamilton or Lagrangian Equations.......

Comment: This is not for JEE: I mean the question was a part of JEE assignment, but I am not interested in a classical way solution. Please stop panicking that this thing is going to come into some competitive exam.

Comment: @SaurabhRaje: This is not important but the site is this- [click here](http://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath523/kmath523.htm)

Comment: well, i have two yrs left to panic, btw, what coaching classes and correspondence do you recommend?

Comment: @Mr.ØØ7 Let me get this straight. You were not taught lagrangian and hamiltonian mechanics until high school? In other words, you learned it IN high school? At what age, pray tell, did you learn about these things in an educational setting? And if I may ask, when did you first learn calculus in an educational setting? Thanks!